# Compact array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose i have these pairs of nodes (ID):

- 0   1
- 0   8
- 500 4
- 8   300

I know the number of unique nodes: 6.
How can i save them nto a matrix, without allocating a 500x500 matrix?
Which kind of mapping can be used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You most certainly want a key-value type of storage (hash table, dictionary, whatever). Or go ahead and allocate those 500*500 elements, 250kB ain't big nowadays.

Comment: It's 500x300 only, isn't? That makes 300K for 16bit ints! @H2CO3

Comment: it depends on what you are doing and on what platform. 300k might be fine in system memory or in cache on a PC... but not so everywhere

Comment: "250kB ain't big nowadays"  ...and this attitude is why computers are so damn slow today, compared with how they used to be 20 years ago. I can't find the site, but someone made a test where they compared an ancient mac from early 90s with a modern PC, and the ancient mac came out as the winner. The only reason why the mac won is all the sloppy programming practice on the PC.

Comment: The point is that if the keys only goes up to 500 then allocating the matrix may be the best option. However, if in your application the keys can be higher then you should consider a sparse-matrix solution.

Comment: The fact is that i have 6 nodes, so why allocating a 500x500 matrix when i can allocate a 6x6 matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might want is a sparse-matrix - you can imagine this as an array containing values that correspond to an x,y for indexing the matrix and the value stored there, so that matrices which are mostly zeros can be stored in a small amount of space. The memory overhead of this data structure is O(n) where n is the number of non-zero entries in the matrix.

In practice you can use something other than an actual array for performance benefits since searching through an array for an x,y is costly, particularly if it is not there (the most common case).

One option would be to use fast hash map type structure to store the values by hashing the x,y position to generate a key...

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Answer (score 1):

This is called a sparse matrix, and there are lots of representations you can use. Which one you want depends on what operations you need to be able to do quickly.

Check out the Wikipedia [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) article for details.

Comment: Ok, i'll check it! The important thing is to maintain the "matrix form". My idea is to map the node-id 500 to 5, 300 to 4, 8 to 3, 4 to 2, 1 to 1 and 0 to 0!